# What does '/*/*' mean in tensorflow's Dataset.list_files function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using Tflite. I am learning how to quantize to INT8.
I am  using a Colab tutorial.
"flowers_dir" is a folder containing 5 folders (each one contains different types of flowers).
What does `'/*/*'` mean? My intuition tells me it is to call the content of each folder. Not sure. Is there like a "tutorial" which explains what is it?

```
# A generator that provides a representative dataset
def representative_data_gen():
  dataset_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(flowers_dir + '/*/*')
  for i in range(100):
    image = next(iter(dataset_list))
    image = tf.io.read_file(image)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
    image = tf.cast(image / 255., tf.float32)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    yield [image]
```

Comment: wildcards in the file path

Comment: all the files in sub directories with depth two from flowers_dir

Comment: Filename wildcards tutorial: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/ksh/wildcards.html

Comment: BTW -- code should be provided as **text**, not images. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta.se]. Images of code aren't searchable; they can't be copied/pasted (which makes reproducing a problem unnecessarily difficult); ambiguous fonts can't be corrected for; assistive tools such as screen readers don't work with them; they aren't futureproof for higher screen resolutions or other future display technologies; etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `Dataset.list_files` at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files:

> The `file_pattern` argument should be a small number of glob patterns. If your filenames have already been globbed, use Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames) instead, as re-globbing every filename with list_files may result in poor performance with remote storage systems.

So, we know what you have is a glob pattern. What are glob patterns? Google to the rescue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming). As described therein:

> `*` is a wildcard standing for "any string of characters"

...so, `/*/*` means you have a directory that can contain any string of characters, in which we look for *other* files for which the names can again be literally any string.